# Android Studio RecyclerView Adapter loop getItemViewType()

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview's adapter continuously calls `getItemViewType()` and seems to be no sign to stop.

I also print log in `onBindViewHolder()`, `onCreateViewHolder()`, and viewHolder's bind function, but only getItemViewType get called infinitely.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

My Fragment:

I added log in each function, and didn't see any function be called continuously.

```
public class Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (presenter == null) {
            presenter = new Presenter(this);
        }
        initViewModel();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setRecyclerView();
        //this will modify adapter
        loadData();
        return rootView;
    }
    void initViewModel(){
        messageViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(messageViewModel.class);
        final Observer<ArrayList<WallPost>> wallPostObserver = wallPostList -> {
            //this will modify adapter
            updateRecyclerView(wallPostList);
        };
        messageViewModel.getWallPostsLiveData().observe(this, wallPostObserver);
    }
    public void setRecyclerView() {
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<>(), Repository.getInstance().getMemberData().getValue(), getType());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    }
}
```

My Adapter `getItemViewType(int position)` function:

Adapter `getItemCount()` be called continuously same as `getItemViewType(int position)`.

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (wallPostList.size() == 0) {
            return VIEW1;
        }else if(position >= wallPostList.size()){
            return VIEW7;
        }

        WallPost wallPost = wallPostList.get(position);
        Log.d("Adapter","position:"+position);
        if(wallPost.getStatus().equals(POST_STATUS_REVOKE)){
            return VIEW8;
        }
        switch (wallPost.getType()) {
            case azz:
                return VIEW5;
            case axx:
                return VIEW6;
            case ayy:
            default:
                if(wallPost.getMsgItemList().size() > 0){
                    return VIEW4;
                }else if(StringUtils.checkHasLink(wallPost.getContent())){
                    return VIEW3;
                }else {
                    return VIEW2;
                }
        }
    }
```

Update: cause problem's code

I found the problem cause this, I solve this problem by add a flag in my customize view to restrict not repeat onMeansure, but I don't know why this will make adapter repeat call `getItemViewType(int position)` and `getItemCount()`.

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if(type.equals(SINGLE)){
            info.post(()->{
                halfWidth = (info.getMeasuredWidth()- arrowImageView.getMeasuredWidth())/2;
                name.setMaxWidth(halfWidth-image.getMeasuredWidth());
                tvNoticeTime.setMaxWidth(halfWidth-image.getMeasuredWidth());
            });
        }
        else if(type.equals(MULTI)){
            info.post(()->{
                name.setMaxWidth(info.getMeasuredWidth()-image.getMeasuredWidth() - (int)PixelUtil.convertDpToPixel(8,context));
            });
        }
        else{
            int dis = (int)PixelUtil.convertDpToPixel(8,context);
                info.post(()->{
                name.setMaxWidth(info.getMeasuredWidth()-image.getMeasuredWidth()-dis-
                        infoImageView.getMeasuredWidth()-dis);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the implementation of your recycler view and other important parts of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't, for some reason. But you can tell me what information you want to know, I'll try to provide.

Comment: Without code I can just see that you seem to have 5 objects and the function should be called once the objects are instantiated. Maybe you should check if you have an infinite loop while adding objects to your adapter....

Comment: Actually I have more than 5 object, and when scroll down, there has no repeat object. But why only getItemViewType() be called? Shouldn't onCreateViewHolder() be called too?

Comment: If you do not past your code we can not help you. If you can not post this, just anonymize it, so that you can post it....

Comment: ok I'll take sometime do that.

Comment: My code is too long, stack overflow not allow me to post... What should I do?

Comment: Just upoad the most important parts that show how you implemented the RecyclerView...

Comment: @TIMBLOCKER
I have updated my code, if you need other information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you update your RecyclerView based on the `wallPostObserver` that looks for changes in the `wallPostList`. There could be a problem regaring this because if the List changes there is a chnage in the recycler View and the `getItemViewType` method is called. If you made it so that the recyclerView is only updated once the user chooes to or in fix intervals you wouldn't have the problem. You could fix that by creating a Method that triggers if the List changes (without using an `Observer`) there you could define the max update interval and make is so that you dont always throw away your entire list.

Comment: it's seems not Observer problem, I add log before `updateRecyclerView(wallPostList)`, but log didn't be called continuously.

Comment: I think i found the problem! but it's in my customize view... I change my view's width in  `onMeansure()` using post, but I don't know why this will cause this situation, I have update my code.

Comment: I solve this problem by add a flag in my customize view to restrict not repeat `onMeansure`, but if you know the problem that make adapter repeat call `getItemViewType`, please tell me. Thanks you to answer my question!